# How to create Black shiny plastic floating hoop/torus effect with u-pipe?

Tags: modeling

How to create Black shiny plastic floating hoop/torus effect with u-pipe?

[image: 3dmoddelfrominternet]

I have tried to make a floating u-pipe, but did not work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's more a material than an effect I guess, are you wondering how to make this object (material and shape)?

Comment: hi thanks! yes! how to creat it?

Comment: i mean this solid modell

Comment: so what's wrong with your current object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for the shape you can take a torus with some subdivision surface and then you can add a displace modifier.

Displace modifier settings:

[image]

Texture settings:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: how could it work with u-pipe?

Comment: the principle is the same. Just make the model, subdivide it and give it the displace modifier with the texture

Answer (score 5):

Create a torus, in the *Operator* box choose the right *Minor Radius*:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, shade smooth it, sculpt it a bit with the *Draw* or the *Inflate* brush (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to invert the brush effect):

[image]

Give your object a black color, a low *Roughness* value to make it reflective, plug a *Bump* node into the *Principled BSDF* Normal input, and use a Noise to create fake 3D bumps. If you want the bumps to be real, don't use any *Bump* node, just apply the *Subdivision Surface* modifier and sculpt the object a bit more:

[image]

Comment: thanks！！it works not realy by me, maybe i should try displacement

Comment: please share your file so that I understand why it doesn't work: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: You need to share the link it will give you  :)

Comment: hi thanks, i works with ring, but not with u-pipe........

Comment: what didn't work? the material? maybe be more precise

Comment: i have posted new pictures, it does not work on u-pipe

Comment: ok but what did not work? the shape? the material?

Comment: the shape, it's not floating,maybe i should tray 3d brush?