# how to make a u pipe with floating effect?

Tags: modeling

I have tried to model this u-pipe like the effect on the ring, but it does not work.

Related question:
[Does someone know how to create this effect with u-pipe? (Black shiny plastic floating hoop/torus)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235848/does-someone-know-how-to-create-this-effect)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a shader or how is this related to the title "how do combine the 2 modells"?

Comment: you should try *Adaptive Subdivision*

Comment: thanks!!!! i will try it!

Comment: i am looking for a shader

Comment: When you have created the torus/ring with the glossy material as shown in the linked question you can assign the same material to the U-shaped pipe. Have you done this and it didn't work?